# __hash__, __eq__ and "in" operator

Tags: python, hash

I've seen many questions on `__eq__`, `__hash__` and their relations, and even though I'm stuck with a surprising phenomena I would like to clarify.

I have a dictionary `team` containing many instances of `player` as its keys. The class `player` itself is rather composite but **includes `__hash__` and `__eq__`**. I may also note that `player` includes properties which are dictionaries, which I believe is the cause for the problem.

Anyway, my code is the following:

```
if player in team.keys():
    name, height = team[player]
```

The weird phenomena is that while `player in team` returns `True` (hence the condition is fulfilled and the lower line is executed), the second line raises `KeyError`. I can't figure out how `in` works well, while the keys are not hashed correctly.

Any suggestions?

## Edit:

The `player` class includes the following magic methods. `cnfg_dict` is a dictionary with several user-specified configurations, from which `required_attrs` are used to distinguish between `player` instances (allegedly...).

```
def __init__(self, cnfg_dict):
    self.config_dict = cnfg_dict
    self.required_attrs = ['attr1', 'attr2']

def __eq__(self, other):
    return all([self.config_dict[attr] == other.config_dict[attr] for attr in    self.required_attrs])

def __ne__(self, other):
    required_attrs = ['dt', 'author']
    return any([self.config_dict[attr] != other.config_dict[attr] for attr in required_attrs])

def __repr__(self):
    return str([str(a)+'='+str(self.config_dict[a]) for a in self.required_attrs])

def __hash__(self):
    return hash(repr(self))
```

Comment: You are not using `player in team`; you are using `player in team.keys()`; this only tests equality in a list (in Python 2 at lest). This *does* suggest your objects have an incorrect `__hash__` implementation (objects that are equal *must* have equal `__hash__` values).

Comment: Can you please show us your `__hash__` and `__eq__` implementations? Or, *at the very least*, a reproducible simplified version of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not comfortable with your big bet that objects which equal each other will have the same **repr** function.  Certainly if you are dealing with numbers it's a risk.  Here's an example:

```
 [in] >>> a = {'name': 'Zelaznik', 'height': 6}
 [in] >>> b = {'name': 'Zelaznik', 'height': 6.0}
 [in] >>> a == b
[out] >>> True
 [in] >>> repr(a['height']) == repr(b['height'])
[out] >>> False
```

I'm betting that you are running into this problem with a player's height.

Here's a quick way to solve the **hash** function:

```
def __hash__(self):
    dct = self.confg_dict
    keys = self.required_attr
    return hash(tuple([dct[k] for k in keys]))
```

It also looks like you are dealing with a class "Player" which has a predetermined set of keys, in which case you could make life easier on yourself by using a namedtuple.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Player = namedtuple('Player', ('name', 'height', 'opt_attr1', 'opt_attr2'))
Player.__new__.__defaults__ = (None, None) #Sets default values for last two arguments.
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple